# Parse GUID out of string

Tags: parsing, powershell

I am running into an issue with this following using trim. It is removing some of the GUID. I would like to just get the GUID out of this. If anyone could help it would be appreciative.Thank you in advanced.

```
((Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -eq "OUName"} -Properties LinkedGroupPolicyObjects,gplink) | ForEach-Object {if($_.GPlink){$_.GPlink.Split(",") | ForEach-Object {if($_ -like 'DC=DCNAME*'){if($_.length -gt 10){(((($_).trim('DC=DCNAME;0][LDAP://cn={')).trim('}')) ) }} }}})
```

My output is this:

```
754FF9F1-078A-4E05-913D-4F36572B2FC6
EDDAAB18-2BA6-42E6-A5EC-21B0227BE71A
7DF312DB-EB73-418E-8F64-3E391F4639B7
6E3512-4100-48A3-9A65-4DA17A0E2D87
72EF89D6-2C57-40AC-A116-2CAD89F453ED
2][LDAP://cn={31BB7749-F6DC-4098-8F10-9D8B4B0F0C0A
78528B0-F379-4E8F-A166-ACE1448AF9B2
```

Comment: I believe I am just missing something? I believe I should be using a `-match` with regex

Comment: Some advice: store intermediate results in variables, perform multiple steps. This allows you to inspect the intermediate results and to learn which step does not work as expected. It may be more convenient to use Replace() than Trim() to get rid of the parts you don't want..

Comment: @MartinMaat - Thank you for the insight! I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without your input i cannot be sure, but you might try something like this

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -eq 'OUName'} -Properties LinkedGroupPolicyObjects, gplink | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.GPlink) {
        $_.GPlink.Split(',') | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -like 'DC=DCNAME*' -and $_.length -gt 10) {
                #$_ = $_ -replace 'DC=DCNAME;\d+\]\[LDAP:\/\/cn=\{'
                #$_.trim('}')
                $_ -replace '^.*([a-f0-9]{8}-(?:[a-f0-9]{4}-){3}[a-f0-9]{12}).*$', '$1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was right on the money. `$_ -replace '^.*([a-f0-9]{8}-(?:[a-f0-9]{4}-){3}[a-f0-9]{12}).*$', '$1'` Thank you for your help, it's greatly appreciated. I need to get more familiar with REGEX.... Do you happen to know of any good sites that can explain REGEX to me?

Comment: Regex101.com.  It explains every character and show live results.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how that `DC=..` filter is helping you. The `DC=` part comes after the guid, so since you're splitting on `,`, won't the first GUID be ignored by the time you get a match with `-like 'DC=DCNAME*'`? Ex.

> [LDAP://cn={7BE35F55-E3DF-4D1C-8C3A-38F81F451D86},cn=policies, cn=system,DC=wingtiptoys,**DC=local;2][LDAP://cn={7BE35F55-E3DF-4D1C-8111111}**,cn=......

If you only want to extract the guids, I would just extact  `{GUID}`, like:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -eq "OUName"} -Properties LinkedGroupPolicyObjects, gplink |
ForEach-Object { 
    if($_.GPlink) {
        #Anything between { and }
        [regex]::Matches($gplink,'(?<=\{).*?(?=\})') | ForEach-Object { $_.Value }
    }
}
```